# Sending email using ESMTP and Twisted to GMail just sits there (no errors or anything)

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, twisted

**Update** Figured out why, gmail offers smtp servers on port 465 and 587, 465 is SSL and 587 is TLS and ESMTP wants TLS which is why it doesn't work with 465, the ssl server... I think (I do know it works I am just not definite on why if anyone can explain why please do :))

---

I am trying to send a email using SMTP and Twisted and nothing happens, no errors, no output, and no email.....

**Output**

```
MacBookPro:EmailSender User$ python send_mime_email.py 
What is your email address? [REMOVED]@gmail.com
What is your username (typically same as email address)? [REMOVED]@gmail.com
What is your password? [REMOVED]
What is your smtp server details? smtp.gmail.com:465
-------Email Details-------
Subject: Hello
Body: Hi, how are you?
Attachment: FTP_Commands.txt
-------Logging-------
2013-01-20 20:43:44-0500 [-] Log opened.
2013-01-20 20:43:44-0500 [-] Creating email
2013-01-20 20:43:44-0500 [-] Created Message.
2013-01-20 20:43:44-0500 [-] Starting factory <twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTPSenderFactory instance at 0xa3c508>
2013-01-20 20:43:44-0500 [-] Sending Email
2013-01-20 20:53:44-0500 [ESMTPSender,client] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 5
^C2013-01-20 20:54:47-0500 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2013-01-20 20:54:47-0500 [ESMTPSender,client] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 4
2013-01-20 20:54:47-0500 [-] Main loop terminated.
```

**Code**

```
import sys
import email
import email.mime.application

import sys

from OpenSSL.SSL import SSLv3_METHOD

from twisted.mail.smtp import ESMTPSenderFactory
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log

try:
    from cStringIO import cStringIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO


def create_email(address, subject, body, data):
    print "Creating email"
    # email block

    # text body
    msg = email.mime.Multipart.MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    # send it to ourselves to make it simple
    msg['From'] = address
    msg['To'] = address

    # body
    body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText(body)
    msg.attach(body)
    att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(data, _subtype="binary")
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename="data.bin")
    msg.attach(att)

    print "Created Message."

    # Create a context factory which only allows SSLv3 and does not verify
    # the peer's certificate.
    return str(msg)

def send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, username, password, from_, to, msg):


    contextFactory = ClientContextFactory()
    contextFactory.method = SSLv3_METHOD

    resultDeferred = Deferred()

    mime_obj = StringIO(str(msg))

    senderFactory = ESMTPSenderFactory(
                                       username,
                                       password,
                                       from_,
                                       to,
                                       mime_obj,
                                       resultDeferred,
                                       contextFactory=contextFactory)

    reactor.connectTCP(smtp_server, smtp_port, senderFactory)
    print "Sending Email"
    return resultDeferred



if __name__ == '__main__':
    email_address = raw_input("What is your email address? ")
    username      = raw_input("What is your username (typically same as email address)? ")
    password      = raw_input("What is your password? ")
    sd            = raw_input("What is your smtp server details? ")
    ss, sp        = sd.split(":")
    sp            = int(sp)
    print "-------Email Details-------"
    subject = raw_input("Subject: ")
    body    = raw_input("Body: ")
    attachment_file = raw_input("Attachment: ")
    o = open(attachment_file, "rb")
    data = o.read()
    o.close()
    print "-------Logging-------"

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    email_data = create_email(email_address, subject, body, data)
    send_email(ss, sp, username, password, email_address, email_address, email_data)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some tricky, confusing terminology confusing things here, I think.  "SSL" and "TLS" are actually most commonly used as different names for the **same thing**.  Being slightly stricter about vocabulary (perhaps still not absolutely technically correct though), there is a protocol named "SSLv2" and another protocol named "SSLv3" (an update to SSLv2) and another protocol named "TLSv1" (an update to SSLv3).

Many people say "SSL" to refer to any of these three things, or perhaps all of them.

Also, many people say "TLS" to refer to any of these three things, or perhaps all of them!

Also, there is a separate notion of starting to speak one of these protocols on an established connection which has *already* been used to exchange some (non-encrypted) data.  Sometimes *that* is what people mean when they say "TLS", it's what you mean when you say "TLS" at the top of your question.

What gmail offers on port 465 is an SMTP server with mandatory SSL (either SSLv2, SSLv3, or TLSv1, I haven't checked which) which begins at the very beginning of the connection - ie, before any SMTP traffic has been exchanged.

What gmail offers on port 587 is an SMTP server without any SSL (any of SSLv2, SSLv3, or TLSv1) but which supports the SMTP feature for negotiating a *switch* to turn on SSL at some point later on.

The difference here as far as clients are concerned, of course, is whether they should start an SSL (SSLv2, SSLv3, or TLSv1) as soon as the TCP connection is established or if they should instead begin speaking SMTP and then perhaps later negotiate an "upgrade" to SSL (SSLv2, SSLv3, or TLSv1).

If the client and the server disagree about what exactly should happen here, the result can be a "hung" connection - eg, with the server waiting for the client to start an SSL handshake and the client waiting for the server to send it an SMTP greeting.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it the problem was that I was using smtp.gmail.com:465 not the smtp.gmail.com:587.

Comment: Answers on questions aren't great places to ask questions. ;)